# How do Virtual Machines make possible the use of multiple OS on the same hardware

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine

I'm doing a question list on Operating Systems and this question came up, "How do Virtual Machines make possible the use of multiple OS on the same hardware? Consider the fact that the OS's have absolute control over the hardware". Can someone help me answer this one?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple virtual machines run simultaneously on same hardware in same way as multiple processes run on same hardware. This simultaneous execution becomes possible due to illusion provided to OS that it is the only controlling entity which is running on the hardware. There are terms/concepts of abstraction and indirection used to provide illusion. Virtualization software make VM to think that it is running on its own hardware by abstracting hardware resources. There are some cases where instructions are transparently handled by virtualization software(indirection). Now underlying hardwares provide facilitations to run virtual machines efficiently e.g. Intel VTx/EPT used to give efficient control to virtualized OS over memory and CPU.